# Maintain last modified date for a file between server and local machine

Tags: c#

I am making FileSync kind of service between the server where my website is hosted and my local machine (windows app). From my machine I want to download a file only if it is modified at server.

After investigating on how to do that I came to know that I can compare "Last date modified" of that file on server to what it is on my local machine. Lets say I have this file:

[image]

I am downloading this file via stream to my local machine via C# windows app. When the file is downloaded on my machine its "date modified" gets changed. I have two questions here:

```
How to preserve Last Date modified what was on server?

How should I consider the timezones difference of my machine and
server machine?
```

Comment: can you post the code that you use to retrieve the file from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reset the date by using the the `.LastWriteTime` property of an `FileInfo` instance.
I would suggest getting the original date from your file on the server, downloading it and afterwards setting the date of your written file with some code like this:

```
DateTime originalServerFileTime = ...;

FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(@"YourFile.txt");
fi.LastWriteTime = originalServerFileTime;
```

Comment: Will setting the "LastWriteTime" property edit the "Date Modified" field as highlighted in my image?

Comment: Btw, you can also used `LastWroteTimeUtc` which should help you with time zone problems ;-)